# Django: How to populate database from JSON

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, django-models

I would like to populate my model's DB from this JSON:

```
 {
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "companies.Company",
        "name": "Google",
        "site": "google.com"
    }
}{
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "companies.Company",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Zoho",
        "site": "zoho.com",
    }
}{
    "pk": 3,
    "model": "companies.Company",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Digg",
        "site": "digg.com",
    }
}{
```

I've made my JSON like how the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/) describes but I'm not sure what to do from here!

If anyone knows what I have to do from here I would love some help! Happy to answer any questions about this!

**EDIT:**

I was told to run

```
./manage.py loaddata companies.json
```

When I ran that I got:

> ' django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem
>   installing fixture 'PATH_TO_FILE/companies/fixtures/companies.json':
>   Extra data: line 21 column 2 - line 5586860 column 6 (char 909 -
>   249730297)'

"line 21 column 2 - line 5586860 column 6 (char 909 -249730297)" Being the last character in the file. I also tried removing one whole entry to the model(to eliminate that maybe the last entry was messed up), but I again got the same error with the error referring to the last character in the file again.

**EDIT 2**

Lines 20, and 21 are simply where the first entry ends and the second one begins(Line 20 is the last line in the example shown in the example above):

Line 20: "    }"

Line 21: "}{"

P.S. The reason why it's line 20 and 21 is that there are actually more fields than; name, and site, the one's shown in the question.

Comment: It says that the problem begins in line 21. Please show lines 20 and 21.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added them in the question!

Comment: I would suggest running your json through a json-parser (under Linux, I think I have jsonp).  It looks like your json is not correctly formed.  (You should not have a trailing comma for your last line in the field section, line 21 probably should be },{ (and probably further re-formatted), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid JSON; you can't have a close brace immediately followed by an open brace. You need a comma between them, but in order for that to be valid you'd need the whole file to be enclosed in `[...]`.

Answer (score 3):

With that file inside your "companies/fixtures" directory, you should just have to run

```
./manage.py loaddata your-fixture-filename.json
```

And fixed JSON from your example:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "companies.Company",
        "fields": {
            "name": "Google",
            "site": "google.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "model": "companies.Company",
        "fields": {
            "name": "Zoho",
            "site": "zoho.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 3,
        "model": "companies.Company",
        "fields": {
            "name": "Digg",
            "site": "digg.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the question regarding your answer!

Comment: Can you include your entire JSON file as well?

Comment: My JSON file is over 5M lines!

Comment: Can you include the first few records at least, with all fields? Without any more information, try adding a comma on line 21, so "}{" becomes "},{"

Comment: I have added a few examples!